# How to get the Browser Key for GCM as per the latest Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I want to get the GCM Browser Key in the Developer Console, but the latest Developer Console doesn'tshow the Browser Key selection.

If I click <kbd>Credentials</kbd>, it doesn't show anything apart from one single key. I don't know what is the procedure to get the Browser key.

If anyone knows let solve my problem. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: There is now a visible note in the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) saying:

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging) tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing configuration.

---

**Update**: It seems that using the Server Keys from the Firebase Console is the sure thing solution.

**If you are just starting to use GCM**, instead of creating a project in the Google Developers Console, do it in the Firebase Console. After creating the project, simply use the auto-generated Server Key. Here are the steps where to find the Server Key:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>CREATE NEW PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Fill in your desired Project Name and select your Country. After this, the new Project should be active.
3. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
4. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

**For old GCM projects**, you can simply Import the project to the Firebase Console:

1. Go to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and click on <kbd>IMPORT PROJECT</kbd>.
2. Select the project you want to import and your country.
3. Click on <kbd>ADD FIREBASE</kbd>. After this, the new Project should be active.
4. Then on left-side panel, click on the **gear button** and select **Project Settings**.
5. Then go to the **Cloud-Messaging Tab**.

---

Basing from the image, you've already generated an API Key. But gonna include the steps for visibility:

1. Go to your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. On the left-pane, click on  <kbd>Credentials</kbd>
3. Under the Credentials Tab, Click on  <kbd>Create Credentials</kbd>
4. Select  <kbd>API Key</kbd>

With that, the API Key is already available. However, it will default as a **No Restriction** key. You may click on <kbd>Restrict Key</kbd> to add the restriction corresponding to what you need the API Key for.

---

I'm not entirely sure, but for a Browser Key, I think you would need to set the ***HTTP referrers (web sites)*** restriction. Since basing from the other restrictions:

- IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) = Server Key
- Android apps = Android Key
- iOS apps = iOS Key

You may try the API Key generated without any restrictions, however, it is highly encouraged for you to add the corresponding restriction as a security measure against *unauthorized usage and quota theft*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Google Developer Console and follow this steps:

1. Create Project
2. Enable Library
3. Create Credential (*)

(*) when u create credential, click on Restrict Key and add your specific Key restriction.